# Issue accessing fileData

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to upload an image file and store it on my server with the path to the location of the file stored on a Mysql data base. I am using an ajax request to send the data but am having serious issues accessing any parts of the file:

**PHP**

```
<input type="file" id="upload_file" name='upload_file' style="width: 0px;height: 0px;">
```

Calls this javascript

```
function upload_photo(user_id) {

    var file = document.getElementById('upload_file')

    /* Create a FormData instance */
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append('user_id', user_id)
    formData.append('file', file)
    request = new ajaxRequest()
    request.open("POST", "edit_details.php", true)
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data")
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4)
            if (this.status == 200)
                if (this.responseText != null)
                    O('page').innerHTML = this.responseText
    }
    request.send(formData)

}
```

The request payload looks like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryFA8fI4XH99ES61F6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

[object HTMLInputElement]
------WebKitFormBoundaryFA8fI4XH99ES61F6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_id"

1001
------WebKitFormBoundaryFA8fI4XH99ES61F6--
```

But when I call a var_dump($_REQUEST) it prints

Any ideas? I've looked at loads but can't work my way through this issue.

I was talking to a professor at my university and he said that "multipart/form-data" can be a pain to work with, and said I may be better using a PUT?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things to mention here with this issue.

First, you will need to make some extra work on the client side, in javascript, to pass multi-part data - I suspect this is what your teacher might have been talking about. For that, I'd refer you to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload).

Second, on the server side, unlike all the other form data, files are not in the $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST array but in their own [$_FILES array](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) instead. I encourage you to read-up on this, but basically, PHP will upload in a temporary location, and you should copy the file to it's final location - then save *that* path into your database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That helps hugely and has saved me a huge amount of time, Thank you very much